# iOS: How to use the same Popover ViewController to controller two separate buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

In RootViewController I have a button *flop1 that when clicked opens PopViewController through segue *segPop and when a selection is chosen and the popover closes, button *flop1 's image is  changed.

I would like to have multiple buttons like *flop1, each which can be populated by its own choosen image, all while using the same PopViewController.

I have connected *flop2 to the same PopViewController, through seque *segPop2.

RootViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segPop"]) {
    currentPopoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [pvc setDelegate:self];
    [pvc setStrPassedValue:[tfUserText text]];
} else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segPop2"]) {
    currentPopoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [pvc setDelegate:self];
    [pvc setStrPassedValue:[tfUserText text]];
}
}

// PopViewControllerDelegate callback function
- (void)dismissPop:(NSString *)value {
NSString *imagefile;
imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",value];
[flop1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagefile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[currentPopoverSegue popoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated: YES]; // dismiss the popover
}

@end
```

How do I create an IF ELSE statement in my

```
- (void)dismissPop:(NSString *)value {
```

to populate *flop2 button with a new image while keeping *flop1 image from changing as well?

I'm sorry if this all seems messy, I have zero programming education and am trying all of this from imitation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this method:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

`sender` is a pointer to the object that invoked the segue (in your case, the button). You can define a property in your popoverViewController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton* buttonThatInvokedMe;
```

set it to the invoking button in your `prepareForSegue`:

```
[pvc setButtonThatInvokedMe:sender];
```

and then return it to a modified dismssPop:

```
- (void)dismissPop:(NSString *)value buttonThatInvokedPopover:(UIButton*)button {
    NSString *imagefile;
    imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",value];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagefile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[currentPopoverSegue popoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated: YES]; 
    // dismiss the popover
}
```

Which you would call from your popOverVC like this:

```
[self.delegate dismissPop:value button:buttonThatInvokedMe]
```

No `if else` required... you should also be able to dispense with the `if else` construction in your `prepareForSegue`.

You will want to make your button pointer-passing types consistent to avoid compilter warnings. If you are certain that the Segue will only be invoked by UIButton types, change your prepareForSegue signature to typecast the sender:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender
```

The other way to do this is to leave it as `id` type, but change your pointer type in the popOverViewController to `id` and pass it back to the delegate method as `id` - but then you will need to typecase it to `UIButton` before calling the `setImage:forState` method as this expects a `UIBUtton` type..

*protocols*

To make this all work without compiler warnings you will also need to declare a protocol for the `dismissPop:` delegate method or use `performSelector`-type method to invoke it indirectly.

Comment: "You can set a property in your popoverViewController with this pointer" What would this property look like? and in this modified -(void)dismissPop does "button" stand for a generic pointer saying "button" that invoked the segue? when i made the changes i get two errors of {Expected Method body} and {Use of undeclared identifier 'button'} (second one is in regard to [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed....

Comment: @Chameleon - see my update. Also check the signature of the delegate method, I had at least one typo in it.